# How can I remove vertical padding from ionic icon?

Tags: html, css, web, ionic-framework, styling

Here is my HTML :

```
<i class="icon ion-email notify-icon"></i>
```

and CSS:

```
.notify-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I set padding to 0 and it removes horizontal padding, but I still see 4-5px of gray padding on top and bottom. How can I solve it?

**Solution:**
As I understood it is impossible to remove vertical padding, so I decided to replace ionic icon with image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you want to use background color but if you wanted gray email icon with size 35px do this.
Full implementation here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLABwK

```
.notify-icon {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

Or if you wanted bordered icon use

```
 <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline notify-icon2 ">
```

And CSS

```
 .notify-icon2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  }
```

Comment: It is an ionic mobile application, I added background color to see padding of icon element on device. I need to remove vertical padding.

Comment: use the second class` ion-ios-email-outline`, as in the answer because what you are asking is modifying the icon itself. To do that you need custom icon itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
.notify-icon {
 color: white;
 font-size: 35px;
 background-color: gray;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
```